How to selectinload when call session.get method?
Imagine there are models User and Phone:
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id: ...
    first_name: ...
    last_name: ...
    phones: Mapped[list["Phone"]] = relationship()


class Phone(Base):
    __tablename__ = "phones"

    id: ...
    number: ...
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id"))
    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship()

I'd like to use session.get which gets instance by PK:
user = session.get(User, user_id)

My question is how to select also phones with this request? I mean how to do selectinload(User.phones)?

You can use session.get(User, 1, options=[selectinload(User.phones)]).
If you check the logs, the query is emitted before the print statement showing that it does eagerly load.
Complete code as follows
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, DeclarativeBase, mapped_column, relationship, Session, selectinload

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    phones: Mapped[list["Phone"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")

class Phone(Base):
    __tablename__ = "phone"
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(User.id))
    user: Mapped[User] = relationship(back_populates="phones")

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///temp.db", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    phone = Phone()
    session.add(phone)
    session.add(User(phones=[phone]))
    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    user = session.get(User, 1, options=[selectinload(User.phones)])
    print("User fetched")
    print(user.phones[0].id)

